# Test for line feed in a string, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the fill color of the text box in an Excel userform, when the user type or press the Enter key to insert a line feed. How to test the presence of line feed in VBA ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeDropOrPaste(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Action As MSForms.fmAction, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If Action = fmActionPaste Then

        TextBox1.BackColor = vbGreen

        On Error Resume Next

        Data.GetFromClipboard

        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & Data.GetText

        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = 13 Then

        TextBox1.BackColor = vbGreen

        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Can we modify it for Ctrl + V, pasting text with line feed as well?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to paste text but nothing changed unless I press Enter key, and when do I this the text is repeated. Any idea?

Comment: Is the TextBox's MultiLine  set to true?  When enter is pressed; my code copies the text from the clipboard and appends it to the end of the TextBox's Text.  Is this the desired result?

Comment: You address OP's requirements quite well. +1

Comment: Hello Thomas, 
We have 3 scenarios:
1- The user types in the text box, if there is line feed (Enter key) then the box turns green,
2- The user paste text by Ctlr+V, if there is line feed in the copied text then the box turns green, and the user may not always press enter key after pasting, 
3- The text is transferred from another text box (by pressing on add button or if criteria is met then textbox1.text = textbox2.text for example, if there is line feed in the text then the box turns green. Can we have solution for points 2 and 3?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You'll have to handle 3 when you transfer the text.